# mysql: improve group by query performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Is there anyway to increase the performance of a query like this:

```
  SELECT MAX(my_index)  
    FROM my_table 
GROUP BY my_type
```

I have an index on my_index and another on my_type. The query takes about 10 seconds once I have millions of records. my_index is unique to each record and autoincrements.

I figure there should be away to do this query quickly if I create a composite index, but I am not sure how. The same query with a composite index on my_index , my_type took twice as long than without it...

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT my_type) FROM my_table`?  Because an index doesn't do much when there's [low cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29)

Comment: Its around 500, the total number of records will be around 50 million, so it should dramatically increase the speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

composite index should be on (my_type,my_index) in that order. If you can make that index the PK, even better (as it orders it physically on the disk).
You have not specified how many records u have, if you have 1000000000000 records, then I would say 10 seconds is pretty fast.

Comment: I have 2 million record in my table
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` GROUP BY `users`.`country_id` 
And it takes Load (48808.7ms) 
the field country_id already indexed, what I should do to make it faster?!!

Comment: what machine r u using? what DB software?

Comment: Hi Itay Moav, My DB is mysql with engine InnoDB 7 the Server OS ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an index on my_type, my_index rather than the other way around. I'm not sure OTTOMH if MySQL supports bi-directional traversal of indexes, but if it doesn't, you want to create the index on my_type, my_index DESC so that the record you're looking for is the first one in the index, not the last.